# Clean LC-Tank drive

Tags: inductor, mosfet-driver, sine

and thankyou for any support.
I have the following circuit
[image: Transmission Circuit]

Here we have a circuit where are two coupled LC-Tanks (1.5MHz) and the second one has a load modulator (MOSFET).

We want to use the coupling as a transmision media and therefore modulate the load with the MOSFET ad sense it on the driving side. (I think NFC is doing it such way. But I can not find any schematic)

The only way I can see to detect the load on the inductor on the driving side is by measuring the current flowing in the 100Ohm resistor. In simulation it works, but only when driven with a sinusoidal wave at natural LC frequency that do not produce current spikes on the drive resistor but rather produces a clean very low amper sine.

I have evaluated different driving solutions where the cleanest sine is produced while including the tank in a LC oscillator. But the current produced through the tank is all about clean and constant as the OP-AMP switch from - supply to + supply.

How will you suggest to drive the LC tank in order to be still able to detect load variations on the coupled inductor?

**EDIT:** 
I'm editing here as i noticed from answers that my question may be misleading. From simulations i'm feeling good with the simple RLC configuration after the sine generator. As i'm transmitting between two guite good coupled inductors with a very low modulation frequency (5-10kHz) and i'm getting a good difference (from 3mA to 15mA peak-to-peak) on the 100Ohm resistor. But i need a circuit that helps me drive LC tank with good sine wave, as when the sine is not clean the current spikes (at carrier frequency) overcome the current difference that is producing the load MOSFET on the transmitter side.

[image]

Comment: try an FM sweep please and insert R to measure impedance for series and parallel for load to drop 50% or -6dB. This circuit with ~50% coupling is used in coaxial double tuned resonance FM IF filters to extend the bandwidth with steep skirts. Same can be done at any f, if you use Mutual coupling.

Answer (score 1):

> How will you suggest to drive the LC tank in order to be still able to
>   detect load variations on the coupled inductor?

Drive it via a small capacitor from the voltage source. In this way the Q of the tank is kept reasonably high and any modulations from the coupled secondary circuit can more easily be seen. You will still need some "loss" component so maybe keep the 100 ohm resistor but put 2.2pF (or maybe a bit bigger) in series with it.

Comment: That is a good point. But maybe better as a comment. As I'm asking how to produce the sine wave as well. With a good (20-40 mA) current supply.

Comment: Keeping the Q high means a better sine is produced. Why not use a colpitts oscillator instead of trying to drive the tank with the right frequency.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a comment, but too big to fit in the comment section.

You never start a filter design for a transmitter receiver by saying " How do you drive a tank better??

You start a design with required parameters like Frequency band, power level, impedance,  band pass gain, Q, band reject levels, insertion loss, return loss or define all the "s parameters" with upper lower limits.

> But FYI, series resonators are driven from Voltage sources with low series R for high Q and parallel tanks are driven from current sources for high Q (like common emitter) but poor for RF current since they often too high impedance for transmitters and easily detuned but ok for receivers.

And complex 5th order filters may have complex parameters for the passband and band-reject for either deep notches for interference rejection impedance matching and is beyond the scope of this question.

> FYI, Here is an **NFC transceiver filter** from Texas Instruments with both Tx and Rx using series resonators and not coupled shunt resonators as you requested. So I suspect your antenna is the series resonator kind.

**Passive high nth order Filter** designs require much reading to learn how they work to get voltage gain, impedance matching , band pass and band reject all working harmoniously. The value of **n** is the number of equivalent reactive L and C components in a filter. Note that the receiver has two pins here and the transmitter has an on-board loop and connector for external.

[image]